# Consider convergence of series: $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } z^k \sin \left(\pi \left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)^{k \text{p1}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was curious with this series
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } z^k \sin \left(\pi  \left(\sqrt{3}+2\right)^{k \text{p1}}\right)$$
where p1 it a natural value positive.

because using Euler Maclaurin formula does not converge, but the series can be the sum with other methods such as wynn epsilon, I have tried to complicate the series a bit and see up to what values ​​the series can be extended using Levin transform in maple seems to be that after $z=3$ it breaks and cannot, using a combination of methods, extended it a little more as seen in the graph and I would like if you could corroborate the calculations
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Consider taking, $$\lim_{k \to \infty}{z^k \sin(\pi(\sqrt{3} + 2)^{k * p1})}$$ Does it approach $0$?

Comment: hint: for any integer $n$, $(2+\sqrt{3})^{n} + (2-\sqrt{3})^{n}$ is an even integer.

Comment: hi but I would like to check the exactly result not and aproximate...